# How to setup VPN bridge between 2 networks

Tags: networking, iptables, openvpn

I have a small ubuntu box which I want to use to bridge 2 networks together over VPN.
One network is in the 192.168.2.0/24 range.
The other network is in the 192.168.93/24 range.

Said ubuntu box is physically (via eth0) connected to the latter network, and has IP 192.168.93.11. On the other hand this box will establish an OpenVPN connection to the router of the first network, in which it will get IP address 192.168.2.162.

So I have one box with 2 IPs:
- eth0: 192.168.93.11
- tap0: 192.168.2.162

In both networks I have a router in which I can configure a static route so that any traffic for the other network is forwarded to the local IP of the ubuntu box.

My question is, how can I get the ubuntu box, presumably using iptables, to forward traffic for the other network, from eth0 to tap0 and vice versa?

Answer (score 0):

Try this on your box after all of your static routes are in place on your routers and your box is connected to the VPN (so that `tap0` is available):

```
root@yourbox:~# sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_foward=1
root@yourbox:~# iptables -A FORWARD -s 192.168.2.0/24 -d 192.168.93.0/24 -j ACCEPT
root@yourbox:~# iptables -A FORWARD -s 192.168.93.0/24 -d 192.168.2.0/24 -j ACCEPT
```

What the above 3 commands will do is

1) Enable IP forwarding in your kernel in order for it to route packets between the two networks

2) Accept any traffic that is coming from the `192.168.2.0/24` network and destined for the `192.168.93.0/24` network

3) Accept any traffic that is coming from the `192.168.93.0/24` network and destined for the `192.168.2.0/24` network

Hope this helps. :)